# Frameworks for a Linux auto updater

Tags: linux, reactjs, web-applications, automatic-updates

Basically, there is a webapp that runs on the localhost on ubuntu.

I want to be able to implement an update or two from my side, and have the few machines that will be running the webapp also receive the update on their end. (All the machines that run the webapp on their localhost also have internet connectivity)

I thought of 
1) A SQL server that holds simply the latest version
2) The webapp connects to the server and checks the latest version and its own version

Beyond this, I'm a bit lost. I was hoping someone could steer me in the right direction for framework or some text that outlines how to implement this sort of thing.

-Apologizing in advance if the question is too vague/non-descriptive

Answer (score 1):

You Could Make your own repository and add it to the repository list of your package manager (Why reinvent the wheel?) [Example Package Repository Creation Tutorial With Apt](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.setup-apt-package-repository.html)

Comment: would this sort of thing work on ubuntu as well? The machines are running ubuntu

Comment: Yes ubuntu also uses APT to update. And Besides you can do that with any Package Manager (at least all that i know)